# Navigation drawer with account switcher with multiple fragments.?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am developing one application having navigation drawer with account switcher in it.

One Fragment of drawer contains tab layout with multiple tabs(in both account). now 
I've created two main Fragments for two separate account, inside that fragment I'm having viewpager with 4 fragments each.

Problem: When i switch account from drawer all tabs are loaded successfully but,
data inside that tabs remains same(Using `recyclerView` inside each tab).

I cannot put my whole code so if you need anything please let me know. Although
I am leaving screenshot for my app hierarchy.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: do you notifydatasetchanged for recyclers after changing accounts?

Comment: changing account will create new fragments instance. so, It will load from scratch.

Comment: @Rainmaker I've created separate adapters for all fragments still data of one account is overlapped with another. and also different layout files.

Comment: Did you use getChildFragmentManager() to load adapters for fragments inside the viewpager? it could be the issue

Comment: @Rainmaker Solved it man thanks for your help. I've forgot create two layouts files for two different viewpagers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it by myself.

I was using same viewpager for both `JobFragment` and `JobWorkerFragment`.
Creating separate file for both solved this problem.